# Split xml to multiple html files with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following a very large xml document, which looks like the following excerpt.
I am able using the some example found on the web to split the file into multiple html files.

My only issue with the resulting files is that they should include the `<h1>` tag and every element before the next `<h1>` and then get the next `<h1>` with the following elements and so on and so forth.

So basically what I need is to be able to produce a file for `<h1 id=h1>` together with the following elements (`<p>`, `<ol>`, `<pre>`)
Currently when the files are created the following elements before the next h1 tag are not included in the created documents. And I don’t know how to adjust the xslt to do that.
Original xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<paragraphs>

<h1 id= "h1">Header One</h1>

<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. </p>

<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  </p>

<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
<ol>
    <li>
        List 1
        </li>
        <li>
            List 2
            </li>

</ol>

            <h1 id= "h2">Header  Two</h1>

            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. </p>

            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    List 3
                    </li
                >
                    <li>
                        List 4
                        </li>

            </ul>

            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>

            <h1 id= "h3">Header  Three</h1>

            <pre>my example one</pre>

            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>

            <pre> Another example</pre>

</paragraphs>
```

the xslt following the example from IBM developer website located here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipmultxsl/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" name="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//h1">
            <xsl:variable name="filename"
                select="concat('output/',@id,'.html')" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$filename" />  <!-- Creating  -->
            <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="html">
                <html><body>
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                </body></html>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The resulting files look like the following :

```
<html>
    <body>Header One</body>
    </html>
```

---

```
<html>
    <body>Header Two</body>
    </html>
```

---

```
<html>
    <body>Header Three</body>
    </html>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: for some reasons I am not able to properly format the message, please bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this...

**XML Input**

```
<paragraphs>
    <h1 id="h1">Header One</h1>
    <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. </p>
    <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. </p>
    <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
    <ol>
        <li> List 1 </li>
        <li> List 2 </li>
    </ol>
    <h1 id="h2">Header Two</h1>
    <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. </p>
    <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
    <ul>
        <li> List 3 </li>
        <li> List 4 </li>
    </ul>
    <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
    <h1 id="h3">Header Three</h1>
    <pre>my example one</pre>
    <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
    <pre> Another example</pre>
</paragraphs>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h1">
            <xsl:result-document href="output/{@id}.html">
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                    </body>
                </html>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output Files**

**h1.html**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h1 id="h1">Header One</h1>
      <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. </p>
      <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. </p>
      <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
      <ol>
         <li> List 1 </li>
         <li> List 2 </li>
      </ol>
   </body>
</html>
```

**h2.html**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h1 id="h2">Header Two</h1>
      <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. </p>
      <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
      <ul>
         <li> List 3 </li>
         <li> List 4 </li>
      </ul>
      <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

**h3.html**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h1 id="h3">Header Three</h1>
      <pre>my example one</pre>
      <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
      <pre> Another example</pre>
   </body>
</html>
```

Also, if you need to perform other transformation tasks you can add an identity transform and use `xsl:apply-templates` instead of `xsl:copy-of`. Then you can add additional templates as needed.

For example, if you wanted to change all `ol` elements to `ul` you would do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h1">
            <xsl:result-document href="output/{@id}.html">
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </body>
                </html>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ol">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```